# Is it necessary to add the json editor plugin while reading the .json file?

Tags: json, payload

`{"AddNewWareHouse": { "default_payload": "{\"client_id\":\"{{clientId}}\",\n  \"warehouse_name\":\"{{warehouseName}}\",\n \"pincode\":500081,\n   \"city\":\"Hyderabad\",\n   \"city_code\":\"TL_HYDRBD_HYDRBD\",\n   \"contact_person\":\"jambu\",\n \"contact_no\":\"78167189108\",\n   \"address\":\"142 ,Velachery Rd,Indira Gandhi Nagar,Velachery,Chennai,Tamil Nadu 600042\",\n    \"company_name\":\"{{companyName}}\",\n \"originator\":\"orion-web\"}" }`I am getting the error "Invalid characters in string. Control characters must be escaped."
in my "Test.json" file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BaXm.png)

Comment: JSON can be edited on any plain text editor. Judging by the error message, it is possible that the file is corroupted, but it may also be a result of line breaks or tabs inside a string token.

Comment: Is there any specific format for adding the .json file?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. JSON itself is a format for representing data.

Comment: Sorry haven't looked at your screenshot beforehand. Where did you copy the JSON from? A console output?

Comment: I did but i then added escape characters

Comment: But you are escaping the wrong characters which only makes it worse. The console representation of strings is how the string would be written in JavaScript code, which does not match a JSON file. Try outputting the string to an HTML element, phreaps a `<textarea>`, and copy it from there.